# Draw attention to and foster discovery of actionable controls

Tags: ios, ios8, uibutton

In an attempt to defer to content, I chose not to use any (navigation or tool) bars.

The app has a tinted `UIButton` which brings up an action sheet (where the user could share the content, and adjust preferences).

What I've seen is that people don't interact with the button.  They merely look at the content.

I'd like to draw attention to the button in a **subtle** initial way, that the user will discover that the content can be shared or changed.

[image: App content and UIButton]

Unsuccessful approaches:

- Changing the button from text to an (action or settings) icon image.  While more recognizable/familiar, I lose out on the title that describes the selected content.
- UIAlertController (displaying instructions for first launch).  Simply too obnoxious.
- Coach marks.  The transparent overlay spoils the initial impression.

What has helped, yet is still unobtrusive:

- Changing the background/foreground colors.  The button's more noticeable on a black background.

I haven't tried occasionally animating the button (until the user finally taps it).

**Are there other or better methods to help a user discover that the app is interactive?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let it glow. Let it glow. Let it glow.

```
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction  animations:^{

    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:5];

    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2f, 1.2f);


} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    view.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0f;
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
}];
```

Mess around with colors, sizes, and timings as needed.